# Solidity statement with a uint on a line by itself

Tags: solidity

I'm working through the Ethernaut challenges, and on [Level 10 ("Re-entrancy")](https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0xe6BA07257a9321e755184FB2F995e0600E78c16D), the `withdraw()` function has a line where the only thing on the line is a `uint`, the `_amount` variable:

[image]

What does this do? In Solidity, what is the effect of a statement that only lists a variable but doesn't overtly perform any operations (such as assignment)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't have a definite answer for you, but at least something.

I've seen this kind of use when the developer wants to silence a warning. An unused variable causes a warning, but in some cases the developer can't avoid introducing the variable. Having just the variable in its own line gets rid of the warning and, if I've understood correctly, doesn't generate any bytecode.

Since the variable is already used in your case, I really can't tell what the point is.